# Breathing techniques for pull up and chin up, or rings or high horizontal bar

Tags: technique, strategy, gymnastics

When we do pull up and chin up, or similar motions in the [Rings (Olympics sports)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_(gymnastics)), or [high horizontal bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_bar),

1. Are there recommended ways to breathe in order to maximize the amounts of pull up and chin up that we can perform?
2. Should we inhale or exhale when we go to the top, or go down to the bottom?

Two possibilities:

(1) Inhale (up at the top), exhale (down to the bottom).

(2) Exhale (up at the top), inhale (down to the bottom).

p.s. There are breathing techniques for jogging, like two inhale and two exhale ---
"in-in-out-out," "in-in-out-out."

For example, see this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd77q9q2gsxq7hv/Screen%20Shot%202021-08-07%20at%207.37.54%20PM.png?dl=0)
[image]

[image]

[image]